# How to create a bootstrap paragraph 'help-block' for a input field in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, content-tag

I´m using Bootstrap with Rail 4 to create a new form for a Model and I want to create a form_group like this:

```
<label for="model_name">Name</label>
<input class="form-control" id="model_name" name="model[name]" placeholder="Your name" type="text">
<p class="help-inline" id="model_name_inline">Help inline</p>
```

In my view I do this:

```
<%= form_for @model, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Your name" %>
<%= content_tag :p, "Help inline", class: "help-inline", id: :name %>

<% end %>
```

But I can´t do the "id" of the content_tag be like the label and input (in this case, 'model_name') adding "inline" to the id

How I can do this? Is there any kind of content_field for custom fields of a form? :-)

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: Thanks to the comment I´ve updated the question with the correct id

Comment: CSS id on an HTML document is suppose to be unique, if you want to reuse it then change it to class instead. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It´s true! I want to set a id generated from the input name like this "model_name_inline" where "model_name" is the id from the input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would extract that into a helper. For example

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def inline_help(help_text, object_name, method)
    content_tag :p, help_text, class: "help-inline", id: "#{object_name}_#{method}_inline"
  end
end
```

You can then use it within your form like this

```
<%= form_for @model, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Your name" %>
<%= inline_help 'Help inline', f.object_name, :name %>

<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.